# How to call java method in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I would like to know if it is possible to call java methods in groovy language. Everybody seems to ask how to call groovy from java code. But I would like to know how it is the other way around. Thanks

Comment: Import the class. Make an instance. Call a method... Are you currently seeing errors when trying this?

Answer (score 1):

Groovy uses the JVM and uses java classes normally.  If you look in the $GROOVY_HOME/lib directory you’ll see there are jar files there, many of which were built from java code.

Add a jar to the classpath and groovy can see its classes (use import to specify what classes you want, exactly like with java). You can also drop jars into $GROOVY_HOME/lib if you want to make them available to groovyconsole or groovysh.